# Retrieve cart value in Stripe and WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I have been following Pippins [tutorial to setup Stripe](http://pippinsplugins.com/stripe-integration-part-3-variable-prices-and-enhanced-plan-handling/) with the WooCommerce cart. I have the plugin working and it is setup so that you can enter the amount you would like the payment to be in the shortcodes.

```
function pippin_stripe_payment_form($atts, $content = null) {

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'amount' => ''
), $atts ) );

global $stripe_options;

ob_start();
```

Does anyone know how I can set the amount to take the figure that is in WooCommerce checkout cart instead of the amount entered in the shortcode? Checkout cart here >
Checkout Cart

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'Stripe free payment gateway for WooCommerce' by SolverCircle.

1. Download and activate the plugin
2. Go to WooCommerce -> Settings -> Checkout
3. At the bottom of the page, under Payment Gateways, there will be the link to Credit Card
4. Click on it and you will be brought to a page.
5. Tick the 'Enable Stripe' checkbox and fill in all the information.

Hope this helps! :)

[What you should see at Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La80D.png)